# Joi unix timestamp set max value

Tags: momentjs, joi

I'm using [Joi](https://github.com/hapijs/joi) package to validate a timestamp field but How can I set a max() value on it, I want the input timestamp to be less than current time stamp

```
var schema = Joi.object().keys({
    t: Joi.date().timestamp('unix').max(moment().unix()),
})
```

but I get the error that:

> child "t" fails because ["t" must be less than or equal to "Sun Jan 18
>   1970 07:35:17 GMT+0330 (IRST)"]

I'm sure that the `moment().unix()` returns the current timestamp, but here it is casted to string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that `max()` and `min()` functions can do the trick but they only work if the threshold is specified in milliseconds.

```
t: Joi.date().timestamp('unix')
.max(moment().unix() * 1000)
.min(moment().subtract('42', 'weeks').unix() * 1000),
```

Comment: You can also do `moment().valueOf()` which gives you a result in milliseconds - see documentation: https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/unix-timestamp-milliseconds/

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like `Joi.date().max()` accepts unix timestamps properly despite being able to specify in your schema that a unix timestamp is expected for incoming values.

If you need to use the current date in your schema you can pass the string `'now'` instead of using the date. Or just make sure you enter the current date in format that `.max()` expects. I tried this using milliseconds and it seems to work as expected. I think Joi is using the default `Date` constructor under the hood to construct dates to compare which expects milliseconds.

```
var schema = Joi.object().keys({
    t: Joi.date().timestamp('unix').max(moment().unix() * 1000)
});
```

From the docs on [date.max()](https://github.com/hapijs/joi/blob/v10.1.0/API.md#datemaxdate)

> Notes: 'now' can be passed in lieu of date so as to always compare relatively to the current date, allowing to explicitly ensure a date is either in the past or in the future.